Bipartite_D3 giving "ReferenceError: vizjs is not defined" error and not runnin script properly
I am new to programing, but I figured how to do most things on R Studio with the help of some frineds and try and error. But I have no idea what is happening when I try to run the Bipartite_D3 package, it just reads the script and I get this error message.
> bipartite_D3(data)
tentando a URL 'http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.1.0.min.js'
Content type 'text/html' length 114 bytes
downloaded 114 bytes

Command for sourcing the URL:
  downloader::source_url("http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.1.0.min.js", sha="f9d9055e9878723a12063b47d4a1a5f58c3eb1e9")
tentando a URL 'http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.1.0.min.js'
Content type 'text/html' length 114 bytes
downloaded 114 bytes

Command for sourcing the URL:
  downloader::source_url("http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.1.0.min.js", sha="f9d9055e9878723a12063b47d4a1a5f58c3eb1e9")
Warning messages:
1: In bipartite_D3(formiga) :
  Making too few facets. Guessing you want 1 row
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  Hash of http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.1.0.min.js doesn't match stored hash, so not downloading in case it has been modified.
                Please save an up-to-date version of the viz.js library as vizjs.js library in the working directory
3: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  Hash of http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.1.0.min.js doesn't match stored hash, so not downloading in case it has been modified.
                Please save an up-to-date version of the viz.js library as vizjs.js library in the working directory

Also "ReferenceError: vizjs is not defined" appears in the 'Viewer' window.
The data is in my directory, it is a matrix and works fine with other packages (Bipartite, iGraph). It does not work with the exemples given in the vignette, as well.
What would normally happen is the creation of a interactive Bipartite Graph on the 'Viewer' window, but nothing besides what I said happens.

The error is telling you that the package is attempting to download a JavaScript file off the public internet but is discarding it because its hash is invalid.  This is a security check.  So, I took a peak at the source code and then went and downloaded the viz.v1.1.0.min.js file myself.  The download does indeed result in an "invalid" file as it appears to be a dead link to a dead domain.
But if you were to download this viz.v1.1.0.min.js file yourself and put it in your R working directory the package won't try to download it and you should be good to go.  That said, I can't really provide an authoritative link to that file, you'll need to google it yourself.

Package maintainer here - as the other respondant pointed out, the original source for the JavaScript library went offline. I've updated the package to CRAN. Once that has gone through, if you reinstall the package (version 0.3.2) it should now work ok again.
